# How to connect ROS to ABB controller

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, abb, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu with ROS Hydro to ABB controller that is using IRB120 robotic arm, but I am unable to understand how to make it connect. I am looking at this [image: image description]. But I am unsure what the robot_ip parameters should be.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263576/how-to-connect-ros-to-abb-controller/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2017-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-09**:
First: please don't use ROS Hydro. It's long been EOLd, and you're missing out on a lot of improvements and support.

Second: can you please tell us where you found the text that you show in your question? I cannot find it in any of the official (ros-i) tutorials.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-06-09**:
I got it from here: http://dspace.uah.es/dspace/handle/10017/20806

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-06-09**:
in chapter 15

**Comment by [Lina](https://answers.ros.org/users/40083/lina/) on 2019-02-18**:
The link, does not work anymore, do you have by any chance, the link updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: after you have completed setting up your controller according to the [official tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials), the `robot_ip` argument should be set to the IP(v4) address of your IRC5 controller (either real or simulated).

This means you'll have to have configured networking correctly on your IRC5, and be able to ping the controller from your ROS PC.

If you only installed ROS Hydro because the PDF you linked instructs you to, I would recommend you start over with either Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) and ROS Indigo, or Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) and ROS Kinetic. The ABB packages are supported on both of these distributions and ROS releases. Then follow the official tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-06-21**:
I was able to ping it. That is working